# Infopath Forms - Change the DataConnections

Tags: infopath, https

I published an InfoPath form to SharePoint that uses a lot of DataConnections.

For example, a comboBox Field receives a list's content.

Recently we changed the access from HTTP to HTTPS and now I need to change the DataConnections as well.

I edited the manifest.xsf and changed "http" to "https" but when trying to access the Form I get the message:

> "Sorry, we can't access https://portal.mydomain.com.br/FormConnections/Users.udcx access is denied"

If I put the URL in my browser I can see the library. I have Full Control in this list.
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance!

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the relative data connection, then I don't think you need to change from http to https on the form manifest.

Comment: Hi, I need to edit 'cause Infopath cannot open the old url!